# What is semi-empirical mass formula? Why semi?

Tags: nuclear-physics, terminology, definition, binding-energy

[Semi-empirical mass formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula) is used in liquid drop model to find binding energy per nucleon expression.

Comment: Please make clear in an edit what you're asking that [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula) doesn't answer. The "semi" part refers to the fact that only the parameters are empirical.

Answer (score 3):

Emperical formula is one which is based on experiment and not on theory. SEMF is based partly on theory and partly on empirical measurements so the name Semiemperical.
Out of 5 energy terms first 3 terms i,e volume, surface and coulomb come from liquid drop model and the last 2 terms i,e asymmetry and pairing energy terms are emperical in nature.